# Qt: Erase background (Windows Aero Glass)

Tags: pyqt, windows-vista, dwm, aero-glass

## Update

see [Using Blur Behind on Windows](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/09/15/using-blur-behind-on-windows/) for an example of using Qt and [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540(VS.85).aspx).[alt text http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/blurbehind2.png](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/blurbehind2.png)

---

### Original question:

I want to create a Windows Aero Glass window with Qt, now it looks like this:
[image]

But after calling some `my_window->repaint()` my window's label becomes broken:
[image]

But now **if I resize the window** slightly, it repaints properly.

---

**The question is**: how do I erase the window background, so that widgets would paint themselves on a clean glass?

---

The short code to reproduce the problem is (Vista with Aero):

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QLabel("This is the text"))

        # let the whole window be a glass
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        from ctypes import windll, c_int, byref
        windll.dwmapi.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(c_int(self.winId()), byref(c_int(-1)))
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.repaint()
```

You can click the window now, or just hit `Alt-Tab` several times.

Anyway, using labels with Aero Glass is not what I need, because QLabel doesn't know how to paint itself with a while glow (like the title of the window). What I need is a general way to clean the "glass".

Comment: Why call repaint?  Can't the window manager just deal with the control drawing on its own?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't repaint — just use Alt-Tab several times, the window will be repainted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use:

```
QPainter p

p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
p.fillRect(boundsRect, QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

This discards the old contents and fills with transparent color.

More info at

- http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Graphics/Performance#QPixmap::setAlphaChannel.28.29
- http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.4/html/com/trolltech/qt/gui/QPainter.CompositionMode.html

Edit:
Better use CompositionMode_Clear and paint the rect with whatever color.

Answer (score 1):

I've been googling for a while so I thought I would share the solution:

replace WA_NoSystemBackground to WA_TranslucentBackground
and forget about the mousepressevent

now the window is transparent aero glass and re-rendered automatically when needed, yay :)