# QT + WM_NCCALCSIZE black showing?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to get a Window created in QT that looks like old Firefox and Opera and stuff (button in the top left of the non client area overlapping the title).

And I got it all working, but I got 2 issues.

1. Randomly my window will turn partly black with random black shapes while resizing. I am unsure of why it does this. But it does. See #1
2. My main container doesn't seem to extend to the full available area, missing 50 or so pixels on the right and bottom. See #2

**#1**

[image]

**#2**

[image]

My code is (it gets ran from QT's nativeEvents).

```
bool MainWindow::winEvent(MSG *msg, long *result)
{
    bool fCallDWP = true;
    BOOL fDwmEnabled = FALSE;
    LRESULT lRet = 0;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HWND hWnd       = msg->hwnd;
    UINT message    = msg->message;
    WPARAM wParam   = msg->wParam;
    LPARAM lParam   = msg->lParam;

    // Winproc worker for custom frame issues.
    hr = DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&fDwmEnabled);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr) || !fDwmEnabled)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (message == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        return hitTestNCA(msg, result);
    }

    fCallDWP = !DwmDefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam, &lRet);

    // Handle window activation.
    if (message == WM_ACTIVATE)
    {
        // Extend the frame into the client area.
        MARGINS margins;

        margins.cxLeftWidth = -1;
        margins.cxRightWidth = -1;
        margins.cyBottomHeight = -1;
        margins.cyTopHeight = -1;

        hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);

        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Handle error.
        }

        fCallDWP = true;
        lRet = 0;
    }

    // Handle the non-client size message.
    if ((message == WM_NCCALCSIZE) && (wParam == TRUE))
    {
        // Calculate new NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS based on custom NCA inset.
        NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *pncsp = reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lParam);

        pncsp->rgrc[0].left   = pncsp->rgrc[0].left   + 0;
        pncsp->rgrc[0].top    = pncsp->rgrc[0].top    + 0;
        pncsp->rgrc[0].right  = pncsp->rgrc[0].right  - 0;
        pncsp->rgrc[0].bottom = pncsp->rgrc[0].bottom - 0;

        lRet = 0;

        // No need to pass the message on to the DefWindowProc.
        fCallDWP = false;
    }

    if (message == WM_GETMINMAXINFO) {
        MINMAXINFO *mmi = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;
        QRect rect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
        mmi->ptMaxSize.x = rect.width();
        mmi->ptMaxSize.y = rect.height()-1;
        mmi->ptMaxPosition.x = 0;
        mmi->ptMaxPosition.y = 0;
        lRet = 0;
        fCallDWP = false;
    }

    if (!fCallDWP)
        *result = lRet;

    return !fCallDWP;
}
```

There has to be a problem somewhere in `WM_NCCALCSIZE` causing these issues. If I remove it (and return to the original window, everything works fine).

Edit: I have determined it has to do with transparency. Though I am not sure what part, but if I remove the widget translucent flag it doesn't do it anymore.